# What is this "&" highlight error for PHP documents in Sublime Text?

Tags: sublimetext3

[image: Sublime Text screenshot]

Editor : Sublime Text 3

Does anyone knows what is that red highlight in the image above?
PHP error? editor(Sublime) error? or something else?
I'm working on a PHP project.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in the way Sublime Text currently highlights `&` characters that are part of a URL. See https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/issues/428 for a discussion about it.

Basically, the problem is that, in HTML, `&` characters can't normally be used on their own, they are supposed to begin a reference to an "entity"/character. In HTML `&` is represented by `&amp;` which stands for "ampersand", the name of this character. However, as per the above discussion, it seems to be valid in some circumstances inside URLs.

There are a couple of ways to "fix" the problem yourself.

- One would be to modify your color scheme to not highlight scope `invalid.illegal.bad-ampersand.html`, but this would affect legitimate invalid uses.
- Another would be to override the HTML syntax definition that ST uses to not mark the ampersand as invalid when inside a `href` etc. ([this](https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/blob/49f0adacd17cc4ab6d82ec0b19faebca0b99b07a/HTML/HTML.sublime-syntax#L208) is the offending line.)
- Probably the easiest solution is just to use `&amp;` in place of `&` in your `href`s for now.

Comment: Thx @Keith Hall. I'm gonna try use another editor for now.

Comment: I wouldn't classify this as a bug, since the docs state that `&` should not be used alone at all in HTML.